# Receiving from Unix domain sockets is not instantenous

Tags: sockets, unix, boost

I am trying to use an `unix domain socket` of type `SOCK_SEQPACKET` as `IPC` mechanism. However, packets are not received as soon as the sender writes them to the socket. Say the sender sends a small packet of 64bytes every two seconds, then sometimes the receiver receives these packets all at once after some many seconds (after 16 packets of 64bytes have been sent usually). What is happening? I am using `boost::asio::socket::async_send()` in one process for sending and `boost::asio::socket::async_receive()` for receiving in the other process (to make it clear, in the above example, async_receive quickly returns 16 times after the ~32s of silence). `async_receive` accept `flags` as argument, I have tried everything, from `MSG_WAITALL` to `MSG_WAITFORONE`, and `MSG_EOR` in the sender, and many other flags, but it looks like there's  sort of buffer in the socket which is not flushed as I'd expect. How can I force this? What is happening in the first place?

EDIT: note that using async vs synchronous send() or receive() has nothing to do with this issue. they do not make any difference with regard to receving the packets "in groups".

Comment: You are using asynchronous sending/receiving - so what do you expect?

Comment: it does not make any difference, using the synchronous receive does not change anything. the receiver does not see any packets for the same amount of seconds. it's not a matter of synchronous vs asynchronous. this is also is the case if I use a sync send.

Comment: Have you tried to use synchronous and see what happens?

Comment: as I said it is the same, the sync version blocks for 32 s , afterwards it reads 16 packets all at once without blocking, one packet per call, then again, it blocks and so on. the sync. sender on the other hand keeps sending at the frequency of 2s /packet